# What information did Saruman have access to that helped him learn the arts of the Enemy?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, sauron, saruman

Saruman is said to have long studied the arts of the enemy. Do these arts consist solely of Ring lore? Or do they consist of other evil technologies/sorceries that Sauron invented?

If he had learned more than just Ring lore, then how is it possible that Saruman had access to any other information about Sauron's arts apart from what may have been written down by the elves of Eregion in the second age?

Answer (score 9):

Saruman's principle interest was Ring lore, but his knowledge of Sauron extended into other areas as well.

> ... Saruman has long studied the arts of the Enemy himself, and thus we have often been able  to forestall him. It was by the devices of Saruman that we drove him from Dol Guldur.
>
> ("The Council of Elrond")

I don't think there is any way to determine how Saruman obtained information of this type. However, there are several possibilities (in addition to the Elven records that you mention):

- We know he journeyed far into the East (where Sauron had long been active) before he took up residence in Isengard in TA 2759.
- He had a palantír, which he may have used to gain information about Sauron's activities and plans.
- He spent a lot of time in the library at Minas Tirith, where there may have been records from Númenórean times (remember that the Akallabêth tells that the Númenóreans fought, subjugated and later worshipped Sauron).

> '"But unless you have more skill even than Saruman, who has studied here long, you will find naught that is not well known to me, who am the master of the lore of this City."
>
> 'So said Denethor. And yet there lie in his hoards many records that few now can read, [...]
>
> ("The Council of Elrond")

- He or his servants may have entered Dol Guldur after the White Council drove Sauron out in TA 2941.
- He or his servants may have entered Mordor while it was abandoned.